# Efficient pseudo-random entry constrained selection

Tags: performance, mariadb-5.5, query-performance

I am looking for a SQL query to pick up a (pseudo)random entry that matches a WHERE clause from a table of ~1,000,000 entries. This query must be as efficient  as possible (must resolve in, at most, 0.01 seconds).

Version
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

The table is defined by the below schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `namepool` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pool` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `namepool_pool_time` (`pool`,`time`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='namepool table';
```

The requirements are as follow:

- The retrieved entry must match the clause

```sql
WHERE pool = '<pool_name>' AND (time < now() OR time IS NULL)
```

- The retrieved entry must be different (pseudo-random is enough) for consecutive queries
- The number of entries in the table is ~1,000,000
- Entries with the same `pool` value have consecutive `id` values in ranges from ~50 up to ~250,000 entries
- Ranges of entries with the same `pool` value can potentially be interleaved with ranges of entries with other `pool` values.

After implementing what is adviced in:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast
- http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/
- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

I came up with the following query, which virtually adds a new column which has the same value for all entries: a random number between 0 and the max value of `id` for an entry that matches the aforementioned WHERE clause. Then I select the first entry that matches the WHERE clause whose `id` value is >= the random number. It resolves in ~0.30 seconds when the `pool` I am searching in has ~250,000 entries.

```sql
SELECT * FROM namepool
AS r1 JOIN(
    SELECT (rand() *
        (
        SELECT max(id) FROM namepool
            WHERE pool = 'test1'
                AND (time < now() OR time IS NULL)
        )
    )
    AS id)
AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
        AND pool = 'test1' AND (time < now() OR time IS NULL)
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

I discovered that the main cause of this low performance is the statement

```sql
SELECT max(id) FROM namepool
WHERE pool = 'test1' AND (time < now() OR time IS NULL)
```

which performs a scan and then resolves in ~0.15 seconds under the previous circumstances.

Comment: *the statement ... which performs a scan* Try to force `namepool_pool_time` key usage... anycase for the `pool` values  which have more than ~50-70k duplicates fullscan is more effective than index scan. Try to replace `SELECT MAX(id) ...` with `SELECT id ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Akina I tried with `SELECT id ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`, but this statement resolves in ~0.70 sec, more than x4 factor compared to its previous counterpart (with `MAX(id)`)

Comment: @Akina Using `USE INDEX(namepool_pool_time)` or `FORCE INDEX(namepool_pool_time)`, i.e, `SELECT id ... USE/FORCE INDEX(namepool_pool_time) ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`. gets the resolve time down to ~0.20 sec, but still too slow. No noticeable performance improvement when using `MAX(id)`.

Comment: *more than x4 factor* & *gets the resolve time down to ~0.20 sec* It is the expected results. But we had to try...

Comment: Is this table: static, rarely updated, frequently updated? and the same for reading access (totally and separately for the displayed query). Does it has ~100Mb size? What do you think about engine=memory copy of this table updated via triggers?

Comment: The table is frequently read and updated, at least 100 times/sec, and its size is ~100MB. I am going to consider your advice of `engine=memory`